# Any software that could convert PDF file to CHM

Tags: pdf

is there any convenient way to convert PDF file to CHM file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of old utilities that I remember of:

- **PDF2CHM**: http://dawningsoft.com/pdf-to-chm.html
- **ABC Amber PDF Converter**: http://www.processtext.com/abcpdf.html

I honestly don't know if they work with current versions of Windows, but I don't think it would harm to try :P.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Both doesn't seem to be working (download links are down)